# What logical fallacy involves claiming the opposition hasn't researched/studied enough?

Tags: fallacies, argumentation

I'm trying to find the name of **any logical fallacy that involves claiming that the opposition hasn't done enough research** to effectively participate in the debate. I've read through a hundred or so fallacies and haven't found a close one.

Statements exemplifying this attitude:

- "Please don't respond unless you've read all the materials I've posted on the topic."
- "If you ever do as much studying as I have, you'll come to the same conclusion."
- "You wouldn't think that if you knew as much as I do."

I feel like it's somewhat related to "The Snow Job" fallacy (overwhelming the audience with marginally-relevant information) in that it requires the opponent to shovel through a lot of specific material in order to participate, but that's not quite it.

It may also be somewhat related to ["Argument from Authority"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority) in that the perpetrator often requires the opposition to consume materials from lots of different "authorities" on the topic (as the perpetrator would believe them to be), however I'm more focused on the unreasonable and ill-defined request that the opposition "do as much research as I have."

Comment: It's appeal to authority, but this is not a logical (formal) fallacy. If you really want to classify it as formal fallacy, it would be a non sequitur ("you haven't studied enough, therefore your answer is wrong", the conclusion does not necessarily follow from the premise)

Comment: What you describe is a tactic that combines [bulverism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulverism) ("assume that your opponent is wrong, and explain his error") with [poisoning the well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well) (presenting information with the intent of discrediting or ridiculing the opponent). It is also similar to how [loaded questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question) work, although in this case we have a loaded request. But the *claim itself* is not a fallacy (mistake in reasoning), it can even be true.

Comment: Thanks for the question Watson!  An argumentative fallacy should be thought of as something that skews the direction of an argument.  If someone has a form of thinking that disposes them towards arguments of certain fallacious types, then we might instead think of them as using a kind of Bias or Heuristic, but these things aren't themselves called "fallacies".  A fallacious argument would be something like "P1: You think X. P2: You haven't done as much reading as you need to.  C: ¬X", and I would call this an example of Poisoning the Well ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_the_well )

Comment: See also [Gish gallop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gish_gallop) (not a fallacy) - where one presents so much "research" that you can't plausibly even attempt to respond to all of it.

Comment: See also [thought-terminating cliché](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought-terminating_clich%C3%A9)

Comment: None of these is a fallacy. At least not until you provide some more context. As far as we know, the person saying these things may well be right.

Comment: These are great answers. Thanks!

Comment: And @Eliran, such statements may be true in specific scenarios, but the question is about claiming that the opposition hasn't done enough research based _solely_ on the fact that they disagree. e.g., "Until you arrive at the same conclusion as I have, it's clear that you haven't studied enough." This type of person may even reject the argument of an actual expert in the field based alone on the fact that they don't agree (and, therefore, couldn't "really" be an expert). I'm not referring to any specific argument, but rather a broad form of intellectual dishonesty I've seen before.

Comment: This sounds similar to the [on the spot fallacy](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/On_the_spot_fallacy).

Comment: I would call this argument a specialized form of the appeal to authority. The advocate claims so much knowledge and experience that the opponent could not possibly find an effective counter argument.

Comment: Sometimes but not necessarily fallacious, and there's a lightbulb joke about it:  *"How many Vietnam vets does it take to screw in a lightbulb?
YOU WOULDN'T KNOW!!!
YOU WEREN'T THERE!"*